# Why an order interval in a finite dimensional Banach space is compact?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, banach-spaces, order-theory

Let $H$ be the set of Hermitian matrices ordered by $P$ the cone  of positive semi-definite matrices and $M,N\in int(P)$ ($int(P)$ is the interior of $P$) such that $M<N$ ($M\le N$ and $M\ne N$).
Why the order-interval $[M, N]$ is compact?

Comment: Note that $[M, N]:=(M+P)\cap (N-P)$.

Comment: You could show, for instance, that it is closed and bounded in the operator norm.